# Is it possible to use both MySQLi and PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Is it possible to use both MySQLi and PDO ? For example, to insert data using MySQLi and then select and work with it using PDO in other part of the project? I have a lot of insert/update code in MySQLi, but decided to switch to PDO?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The data inserted in to a database doesn't care how it got there, or how you get it back out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But keep in mind that you'd have two completely separated connections to the MySQL server in any case. The mysqli_* and PDO_MySQL extensions cannot (currently) share a single connection even though they use the same transport driver ([MySQLnd](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php))

Comment: one of the reasons, why I am switching to PDO, is that I will not need MySQLnd so much

Comment: `switching to PDO, is that I will not need MySQLnd so much` - it does not? In what way does mysqli depend more on the nd driver than pdo?

Comment: I needed get_result functionality which is provided by MySQLnd, but could not install it on MAMP. Lots of people have just recommended to switch to PDO. I understood it like  it's implemented differently in PDO

Answer (score 2):

it is, you just need to configure the connection for both.

You're much better off converting it all to PDO though. It will save time in the long run fixing all the security vulnerabilities in Mysqli

Comment: I'v already spent a lot of time understanding security in MySQli :(

Comment: I know it has been 7 years, but it's always important to remember that understanding the problem is only half the battle. It's always hard to make sure you'll get it right 100% of the time, and it only takes 1 slip for you to have a problem in your hands.